# How does Instagram profile photo zoom logic work?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

There are some sites that show the person's profile photo larger after typing their Instagram username.Instagram does not show us large photos. Usually like standard thumbnail (150x150).With what information does the programming technology on this site zoom the photo? Otherwise, this is Instagram's original site, or how this site can one access the photo?

Understanding the logic of Instagram profile photo zoom application.

I tried to understand the Instagram profile photo enlargement mechanism.